# In Some Android devices, CalenderPickerView shows wrong day for any date

Tags: android, calendar

I am facing issue where Android device showing wrong day for any date in CalenderPickerView. I faced this problem in Mi note 5 pro and Samsung Galaxy A5. This is not happening for all Mi note 5 pro or Samsung galaxy A5, it happens in some devices. I am attaching the screenshot. Please help me to understand the issue and how to fix it. Below is the code for Calendar i have used

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
    nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    Date today = new Date();
    today= c.getTime();
    date1 = today;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date2);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
    date2 = c.getTime();
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US);

    try {


        depature_date_text.setText(date_display.format(date1));
        if(Constants.MODE==2) {


            return_date_text.setText(date_display.format(date2));
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //add one year to calendar from todays date
    if (mode==2) {

        calendar_view.init(today, nextYear.getTime())
                .inMode(CalendarPickerView.SelectionMode.RANGE);
    } else {
        //rel_return.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //return_highlight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rel_return.setEnabled(false);
        calendar_view.init(today, nextYear.getTime())
                .inMode(CalendarPickerView.SelectionMode.SINGLE);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: mention your calendar code

Comment: @Abhinav Gupta, I have added the calender code

Answer (score 0):

This might be because, when you call Calendar,it returns the day of the week in the form of integers from 0-6 or in some mobiles 1-7.
To get rid off this you may have to add extra piece of code

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String i="";
    int dayofWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 
                    if (dayOfWeek == 1) {
                        i = "Sunday";
                    } else if (dayOfWeek == 2) {
                        i = "Monday";
                    } else if (dayOfWeek == 3) {
                        i = "Tuesday";
                    } else if (dayOfWeek == 4) {
                        i = "Wednesday";
                    } else if (dayOfWeek == 5) {
                        i = "Thursday";
                    } else if (dayOfWeek == 6) {
                        i = "Friday";
                    } else if (dayOfWeek == 7) {
                        i = "Saturday";
                    }
```

This will return the day perfectly in every device.
place the i wherever you want